# get records from two different tables based on their respective datetime fields - mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch data from two different tables `orders` and `order_returns` by comparing their respective datetime field.

Below is the schema

```
ORDERS table
    order_id | date_1 | amount
       1      10-10-18    50
       2      11-10-18    100
       3      13-10-18    200
```

`Order returns table`

```
order_return_id | order_id | date_2
     1              3       13-10-18
```

The output should be

```
order_id  | order_return_id  | amount | date_1  | date_2
  1               NULL           50      10-10-18   NULL
  2               NULL           100     11-10-18   NULL
  3               1              200     13-10-18   13-10-18
```

I know this could be achieved by doing a left join but I want to display the result in this way. Below is the link

```
the order_returns data should appear when the date_1 matches date_2
```

https://ibb.co/kfX18p

The red part should appear where the arrow points

Answer (score 1):

Use left join

```
select order_id , order_return_id, amount,date_1 ,date_2
from ORDERS left join Orderreturns
on date_1=date_2
```

Comment: Got your point. Thanks. Now here is a second scenario. What if the left join condition does not match and I still want the data from the right table. What could be the solution??